# Machine learning and linear regression - Expected 2D array, reshape data

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, linear-regression, prediction

I'm **very** new to machine learning, and so using a Pokemon dataset, I decided to write a test program to predict a "catch rate" based on the "total" data. I wanted to use linear regression for my training data. But when I run my program, I get the following error:

> Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=['190' '90' '45' '125'
> '190' '75' '45' '120' '200' '45' '190' '60' '225'  '90' '3' '45' '150'
> '120' '45' '3' '3' '255' '90' '45' '45' '45' '255'  '225' '190' '190'
> '255' '90' '45' '45' '30' '45' '45' '90' '190' '90' '45'  '90' '60'
> '45' '60' '75' '55' '75' '45' '45' '3' '255' '45' '3' '45' '90'  '190'
> '60' '190' '200' '225' '75' '45' '45' '45' '200' '120' '120' '255'
> '60' '45' '45' '75' '60' '60' '190' '75' '45' '120' '190' '200' '235'
> '45'  '45' '90' '30' '45' '45' '170' '235' '45' '190' '60' '75' '180'
> '45' '235'  '190' '45' '120' '45' '75' '190' '45' '45' '45' '45' '45'
> '75' '45' '45'  '190' '45' '75' '3' '45' '60' '200' '45' '45' '255'
> '255' '120' '45' '255'  '125' '120' '60' '45' '45' '60' '255' '45'
> '180' '60' '45' '60' '3' '25'  '120' '45' '3' '3' '45' '75' '30' '45'
> '255' '30' '75' '255' '255' '180'  '255' '45' '45' '120' '255' '75'
> '30' '45' '75' '45' '255' '120' '45' '45'  '45' '190' '45' '75' '45'
> '45' '3' '60' '30' '60' '200' '45' '75' '120'  '25' '255' '45' '255'
> '200' '190' '190' '120' '45' '90' '170' '45' '75'  '60' '100' '45'
> '45' '90' '45' '45' '45' '255' '60' '90' '140' '45' '90'  '75' '200'
> '45' '45' '255' '120' '3' '45' '75' '200' '255' '225' '120'  '120'
> '200' '45' '45' '50' '190' '45' '45' '45' '45' '45' '45' '30' '3'  '3'
> '255' '45' '45' '255' '120' '225' '45' '75' '75' '45' '60' '255' '60'
> '60' '45' '120' '255' '45' '225' '255' '45' '45' '3' '255' '190' '30'
> '190' '45' '45' '120' '75' '25' '75' '255' '45' '120' '100' '3' '65'
> '45'  '75' '180' '45' '45' '3' '255' '45' '45' '90' '225' '190' '45'
> '255' '3'  '190' '70' '3' '120' '45' '45' '50' '200' '190' '255' '55'
> '150' '45' '3'  '25' '60' '45' '120' '45' '205' '60' '45' '45' '255'
> '30' '120' '75' '45'  '90' '45' '45' '60' '190' '45' '45' '90' '45'
> '3' '75' '90' '200' '180'  '45' '45' '75' '90' '45' '3' '120' '45'
> '45' '45' '45' '75' '45' '155'  '45' '55' '45' '30' '45' '150' '255'
> '45' '75' '180' '15' '190' '255' '75'  '190' '45' '190' '90' '255'
> '45' '45' '45' '190' '3' '60' '45' '60' '60'  '255' '25' '145' '45'
> '45' '120' '50' '45' '120' '45' '255' '45' '45' '45'  '50' '225' '30'
> '75' '120' '3' '45' '120' '30' '45' '255' '90' '3' '3'  '120' '45'
> '127' '120' '200' '255' '25' '45' '75' '120' '255' '190' '220'  '45'
> '65' '45' '90' '60' '200' '190' '190' '120' '190' '90' '45' '120'
> '75' '190' '75' '90' '120' '90' '75' '45' '190' '45' '100' '60' '3'
> '45'  '90' '190' '255' '45' '190' '45' '45' '25' '60' '60' '45' '190'
> '45' '190'  '30' '190' '45' '190' '255' '45' '45' '3' '120' '3' '45'
> '35' '120' '190'  '255' '190' '45' '45' '45' '45' '255' '190' '45'
> '190' '225' '45' '190'  '255' '45' '190' '45' '255' '75' '45' '90'
> '120' '30' '180' '190' '100'  '255' '235' '75' '60' '190' '160' '45'
> '3' '120' '45' '3' '120' '45' '45'  '45' '127' '75' '190' '140' '75'
> '225' '60' '45' '75' '120' '190' '190'  '90' '3' '45' '150' '120' '30'
> '50' '45' '60' '190' '255' '125' '120' '75'  '60' '90' '140'].
>
> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single
> feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

To fix my error, I tried reshaping my x_train list, as that seems to be the one referred to above, but I'm still getting the same error. Perhaps my syntax is off? I tried `x_train.reshape(-1, 1)` and `x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 1)` from another suggestion I found, but no go.

Here is the (rough) code that I've written so far:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import csv

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Create lists and append data -- we want to predict the catch rate!
total = []
catch_rate = []

with open("pokemon.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # skip header
    for row in reader:
        total.append(row[5])
        catch_rate.append(row[21])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = 
cross_validation.train_test_split(catch_rate, total, test_size=0.25, 
random_state=0)


# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Make predictions using the testing set
pokemon_y_pred = regr.predict(x_test)

# Plot outputs
plt.scatter(x_test, y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(x_test, pokemon_y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

Maybe I've overlooked something else in my understanding of the code? Again, I'm teaching myself, so I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: exception stacktrace?

Comment: The error says that the model cannot understand where you are giving dataset which has one instance with many features or data with many instances with only one feature. That's why it asks you to reshape. (I assume you have many rows with 1 feature so `.reshape(-1, 1)` should work). If it does not work after you reshape `X` to make it 2D matrix, you should show the error you face.

Comment: @SeljukGülcan Maybe I'm using the .reshape in the wrong spot in my code? I added `x_train.reshape(-1, 1)` after splitting my test data but before training my model using the training sets and got a new error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'`

Comment: @GarrettMcClure, the position seems right. try `x_train = np.array(x_train).reshape(-1, 1)`. You should also do the same thing to `x_test` as well.

Comment: @SeljukGülcan Now I'm getting a new error: `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'`

Comment: Try something like `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1,1))` instead

Comment: @CsuGouv Unfortunately, that still doesn't work.

Comment: May you specify the line where the error is raised ?

Comment: @ASTEFANI Sure, my editor says it's at line 140 in safe_sparse_dot, which shows `return np.dot(a, b)`. This comes from the `extmath.py` file.

Comment: Thanks, but we need also to know the line inside the (rough) code (not the last line)

Comment: @ASTEFANI If it isn't coming from the added code from above, perhaps it's coming from the `pokemon_y_pred = regr.predict(x_test)` line of code?

Comment: Could you share the first 5 lines of the csv file please, or link to the csv file

Comment: @ASTEFANI Here is the dataset: `https://www.kaggle.com/alopez247/pokemon`

Comment: The error is raised on line 30: `regr.fit(x_train, y_train)`

Comment: Try to reshape your arrays as @SeljukGülcan told you, but do it on `total` and `catch_rate` before data splitting : `total = np.array(total).reshape(-1,1)` and `catch_rate = np.array(catch_rate).reshape(-1,1)`

Comment: @CsuGouv Still gives the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, but I noticed something. Your numbers are not int but strings. That is why you get the error `Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') ...` after reshaping.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas` dataframe instead of `list` type.
Note also that the first element of `train_test_split` function need to be a dataframe with at least two columns.

---

So assuming your csv file look like:

```
Id,Name,Type_1,Type_2,Total,HP,Attack,Defense,Sp_Atk,Sp_Def,Speed,Generation,isLegendary,Color,hasGender,Pr_Male,Egg_Group_1,Egg_Group_2,hasMegaEvolution,Height_m,Weight_kg,Catch_Rate
1,Bulbasaur,Grass,Poison,318,45,49,49,65,65,45,1,False,Green,True,0.875,Monster,Grass,False,0.71,6.9,45
2,Ivysaur,Grass,Poison,405,60,62,63,80,80,60,1,False,Green,True,0.875,Monster,Grass,False,0.99,13,45
3,Venusaur,Grass,Poison,525,80,82,83,100,100,80,1,False,Green,True,0.875,Monster,Grass,True,2.01,100,45
4,Charmander,Fire,,309,39,52,43,60,50,65,1,False,Red,True,0.875,Monster,Dragon,False,0.61,8.5,45
5,Charmeleon,Fire,,405,58,64,58,80,65,80,1,False,Red,True,0.875,Monster,Dragon,False,1.09,19,45
```

And using the following code:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd #import pandas

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

#load csv file with pandas
df = pd.read_csv("pokemon.csv")
#remove all string columns
df = df.drop(['Name', 'Type_1','Type_2','Color','Egg_Group_1','Egg_Group_2'], axis=1)

y= df.Catch_Rate

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(df, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)


# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Make predictions using the testing set
pokemon_y_pred = regr.predict(x_test)

print pokemon_y_pred


# [ code continuation ...]
```

You will get:

```
[ 45.  45.]
```

Comment: Strange, I get another value error: `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').` I also removed the TRUE/FALSE tables as well: `df = df.drop(['Name', 'Type_1','Type_2','isLegendary','Color','hasGender','Egg_Group_1','Egg_Group_2','hasMegaEvolution','Body_Style'], axis=1)`.